# LibGit2SharpException while fetching: 'too many redirects or authentication replays'

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I've got a problem while trying to fetch from my repository using libgit2sharp.

I'm trying to fetch from my Github repository. It is cloned via https. As soon as the fetch command runs, the LibGit2SharpException throws saying: `"too many redirects or authentication replays".`

I've read a few other questions here on so, but none of them helped so far. Using `DefaultCredentials` only leads to a 401 error, which makes sense.

Does anybody know how to solve this one?

```
using Repository repo = new Repository(@"path\to\repo");

Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

IEnumerable<string> refSpec = remote.FetchRefSpecs.Select(x => x.Specification);

Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials { Username = "USER", Password = "PASS" };

Credentials Handler(string url, string fromUrl, SupportedCredentialTypes types) => credentials;

FetchOptions options = new FetchOptions { CredentialsProvider = Handler };

string log = "Fetching remote";

Commands.Fetch(repo, remote.Name, refSpec, options, log);
```

Edit: As far as I figured out, the problem is, that it's a private repo, since I can fetch public ones from github. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue with using a PersonalAccessToken from Github. The Token then can be used as the password of the credentials

Answer (score -1):

I solve this with instructions below

```
using (var repo = new Repository(destinationDirectory))
{
    // Stage all changes
    Commands.Stage(repo, "*");

    // Create the commit
    var author = new Signature("User_Name", "User_Email", DateTimeOffset.Now);
    var committer = author;
    var commit = repo.Commit("Commit message", author, committer);


     //Push the commit to the remote repository
    var remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];

    var pushOptions = new PushOptions
        {
            CredentialsProvider = new CredentialsHandler(
                    (url, usernameFromUrl, types) =>
                        new UsernamePasswordCredentials()
                        {
                                Username = "x-access-token",
                                Password = "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN (instructions below to genreate)"
                        }
                ),
        };

    repo.Network.Push(remote, @"refs/heads/main", pushOptions);
}
```

1. Go to the GitHub website and log in to your account.
2. Click on your profile picture in the top-right corner, and then click on "Settings".
3. In the left sidebar, click on "Developer settings".
4. In the left sidebar, click on "Personal access tokens".
5. Click on the "Generate new token" button.
6. Provide a descriptive note for the token to identify its purpose.
7. Under "Select scopes", choose the appropriate permissions for the token based on the actions you need to perform, such as repository access, commit creation, etc.
8. Click on the "Generate token" button.
9. GitHub will generate a new Personal Access Token for you. Copy the token value.
10. Replace "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" in the code snippet with the actual token you copied.